# Best place for code that will be reused in module

Tags: magento2

I have searched high and low and can't really find a good answer on this. I would like to create a class that contains a method/function that I can easily reuse in controllers, blocks and etc instead of copying the same method in many classes.

For example, I want to create a class and method that will delete specific cookies. I already know how to delete the cookies but I'm trying to figure out the best place to create this reusable class. I figured since in a way it is altering data (cookies) a model would be the best place. Am I right?

In M1 I would have created a model for this. However, the structure of M2 has changed so much I wanted to see what is recommended just to be sure. I'm still learning about the contracts and interfaces and etc. I also understand that plugins are to be used to change data or methods. I just want to be sure I place it in the best place and understand the reason why.

I would like to create a class that the construct method can make use of the following:

```
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
```

If someone can create and example of the top half of the class down to the `__construct` method/injector that would be awesome! I just want to understand where you would place this, why and what you extend and/or implement. Thank you in advance!

Update:

I came up with this.

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Cookie extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_sessionManager;

    /**
     * @var MetadataFactory
     */
    protected $_cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var Manager
     */
    protected $_cookieManager;

    public function __construct(
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager,
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
    ) {
        $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
        $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    ....

}
```

Then in my controller I inject this class into the construct method:

```
protected $_cookieModel;

public function __construct(
Context $context,
\NameSpace\Module\Model\Cookie $cookieModel,
....

) {
    $this->_cookieModel = $cookieModel;
}
```

And then I simply call it from the controller `$this->_cookieModel->deleteCookies();`

Does this look ok? If not, what would you have done differently?

Comment: I think this looks good.

Comment: Thank you Toan!